# Differentiating the translation of "Bilingual Education" and "Dual Language Education" into Chinese?

Tags: translation, word-choice, word, word-requests, terminology

While I know, "Bilingual Education" can be translated as "**双语教学**" or "**双语教育**".

（Note that "教育" and "教学" can be used interchangeable. With the former emphasizing on education as a whole, and the latter emphasizing on the pedagogy and students' both physical and mental development.）

I am unsure of the official or accurate translation of "Dual Language Education" (also known as "Dual Lingual Education").
Based on one source, it has translated dual language education as "**双向式双语教育**“.

Analyzing it, I can *interpret* it as a category of bilingual education. As it can be a bilingual program, that is split into two segments.

As shown:
双向式 + 双语教育

**双向***式* = **Two-way** *style*

**双语**教育 = **Bilingual** *Education*

= **双向**式**双语**教育

Translated literally as "Two-way Bilingual Education" (meaning Dual Language).

---

However, I have also seen some sources translate it as "**双语沉浸式教学**" (Bilingual Total Immersion Program)

沉浸式教学 would mean "Total Immersion Program". Which would mean the opposite without 双语- ("Bilingual" at the front). However, with the word "双语-" at the front it would make sense. As it means to be totally immersed in one language, but during different periods of the school day.)

---

Final thought: While people I have come into contact with states the two as different education programs. I have noticed from analyzing some of the translation to conclude that "dual language education", may just be a category of bilingual education. As both are for the purpose of bilingualism.

*My final understanding:*

**Bilingual Education**

= **双语教育**

---

**Dual Language Education**

= **双向式双语教育**

or

= **双语沉浸式教学**

---

I am not sure if my thoughts are correct. What do you all think?

Comment: I just need to say, I think its impossible to differentiate these, at least as the question is currently framed.  bilingual itself by definition means dual language, and they are interchangable in english ((although dual lingual would be the less common term)).

Comment: I would say that although bilingual by itself means dual language. In the content of the field of education, it can be categorized with different forms of instruction. This is because in the years of teaching, they have experimented a lot. Here are some examples: 1) Full Immersion Classrooms: only allowed one language, being the targeted language. 2)  Students' native language and targetted language instructions mixed. 3) Two languages are instructed by during different periods. (Second one = traditional bilingual classroom. Third one =  category known as dual language)

Comment: its possible some individual schools may use this as a distinction, which is fine.  In general both two and three would be bilingual and dual language, interchangeably.  Maybe its better to say that any differences between the two will need to rely on context and not an inherent difference.

Comment: I see I see! So maybe it's the context!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, 双语学校 (bilingual schools) in China are similar to 国际学校 (international schools). Those schools in China are for childrens of forieners who lives in China and Chinese students who want to be prepared for going abroad in the future.

The names 双语学校 and 双语幼儿园 are also used in the USA and other overseas Chinese communities. Most of the children will learn Chinese as their second language. But those schools are very different from 中文学校 in the USA that operates only on weekends.

双语教学 (bilingual teaching) means to teach the classes other than foreign languages, such as mathematics and physics, in English or othen foreign languages. Those classes are usually provided in Universities.

双语教育 (bilingual education) may have a broader meaning and application. It can include any activities related to education that involve the native language and a foriegn language. Bilingual education can include bilingual school and bilingual teaching.

Comment: Interesting. I never knew  国际学校 existed. Also, I agree that Bilingual education can refer to both school and teaching. It is very general!

Comment: I do have to say that some 中文学校 does operate on weekdays. As I have been a intern at one that operates afterschool (4 - 6 pm ish)